# Getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when modifiying SQL in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm perplexed by one of Microsoft's oh so useful error messages when I try to modify the SQL behind a dataset.  The original SQL is

```
Select * from Denormalized_V
where (@Instructor = '<ALL>' and [Section Code] in (@SectionList)) or
      (@Instructor <> '<ALL>' and [Section code] in (@SectionList) and [Instructor Name]     Like @Instructor)
order by [subject], [course], [course section], [respondent code]
```

and the new SQL is:

```
Select * from Denormalized_V
where Term = @Term and [Subject] = @Subject and Course in (@Courses) and
  ((@Instructors = '<ALL>') or ([Instructor Pid] = @Instructors or [Instructor Pid] = 'ALL')) and [Course Section] in (@Sections)
order by [subject], [course], [course section], [respondent code]
```

I do the execute thing from within the query designer and it returns values, so I am at a loss as to why I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error the minute I hit Ok.

Has anyone seen this type pf behavior before?

Comment: Which version of SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  It was my error.  I had a parameter that was misnamed in the SQL.  One of those simple mistakes that takes forever to catch.